# Root password change reverted after reboot

Tags: server, password, root

I've just installed a new Ubuntu server. It is a virtual machine hosted on Hyper-V. I'm trying to change the root password using the following commands:

```
sudo passwd
```

and then entering the new password.

Everything look fine until I reboot the server. Then only the old password works.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try sudo passwd root If you never got a confirm message you never changed it in the first place.

Comment: Hello David, I received the message: passwd: password updated successfully but when I rebooted the server, still the same issue.

Comment: You also should have said in the question what you had tried and I would not have told you to do something you had already done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo passwd
```

changes the *admin* password (that is the user used to create the system with) not the password for root. Anything related to root does not require `sudo` and will mess things up (as Ubuntu expects you meant the admin user when using `sudo`).

> change the root password.

You need to first change to **root** using

```
sudo -i
```

(requires the admin password) and then change the password for root with:

```
passwd
```

Mind that Ubuntu is not meant to be used with root. If you want that it is better to change to a system that does use that out of the box. Using root on Ubuntu can have unwanted side effects. `sudo` is a slight improvement over using root when it comes to security: hackers need your admin account name and the password. Using root means the former is known to all.